# How do I make a google charts larger by scale

Tags: html, image, api, google-visualization

I've just started using google charts and want to use it in a small project I'm workin on but I've bumped into a problem. The thing is I want the charts rather big at a static size and look good but I'm generating the charts dynamically with php. Now the problem is that I can't get it to scale properly in width but height is perfectly fine.

Here's an example chart I've generated:

[image: chart]

Parameters:

cht=bvo&chs=400x400
chd=t:1,4,1
chxr=2,0,4,1
chds=0,4
chco=4d89f9
chxt=x,x,y,y
chxl=0:|3|7|26|1:|Correct+answers|3:|People

You see how the chart fills the 400px of height but not the width. I've searched and look through the api but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is not to scale the bar width to fit the width of the chart.  Adding `chbh=a` will probably do what you want.

See the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#chbh) for more information on controlling bar width and spacing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thanks for the link, that worked as I wanted.